# Why is Flask redirecting from project directory to root directory?

Tags: python, flask, cpanel

I'm working on a Flask-based Python web app created through cPanel. Everything is fine when run locally, but on the server, I can't make the app stick to the templates file in the app's subdirectory when there's a subdirectory of the same name in the root directory.

So if I put this URL in the browser:

mysite.org/flaskproject/about

--and there's an "about" subdirectory in the root, the browser jumps to that one and renders

mysite.org/about

On the other hand, mysite.org/flaskproject/home works fine, presumably because there's no folder of the same name in the root directory.

How do I persuade Flask to ignore mysite.org/about and go straight to mysite.org/flaskproject/about ?

Here is the routing from the main application file:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html', title='About')
```